# Highcharts : How can I add minor ticks on xAxis with month categories

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get something like this:

[image]

and I'm having trouble with adding those small ticks on the xAxis?

The code I have right now looks something like this: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w4nu0skv/2/)

How in the world do I get those tiny tick marks between the dates? I've read abount tickIntervals, and minorTickIntervals in tha API documentation, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for any help and guidance.

**EDIT:** It seems that tick intervals don't work when I have categories in the xAxis options.

```
xAxis: {
                //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          minorGridLineWidth: 0,
          minorTickPosition:'inside',
          minorTickLength:10,
          minorTickWidth: 1,
          minorTickInterval:0.1,
        },
```

Comment: Hi Slavenko, Are you sure that you need to use categories on your xAxis? It looks that better idea for you may be to use datetime type of your axis. You can read information about minorTicks and with categories in Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minorTickInterval

Comment: Ah, you might be on to something, this is already looking better: http://jsfiddle.net/slavenko/e08rm9n0/